# How do I import definitions from another file in a Go program?

Tags: go, scope, package

I have the following files:

`gopackage/main.go`:

```
package main

func main () {
  foo();
}
```

`gopackage/otherfile.go`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func foo() {
  fmt.Print("foo\n")
}
```

Apparently, the reference to `foo` from `main.go` does not resolve to the definition of `foo` in `otherfile.go`:

```
> go run main.go
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:4: undefined: foo
```

Why not? I have been told that all files in the same directory comprise a single package, which is a single scope.

Comment: Required reading: [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Compile and run Go program](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program)
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> go run [build flags] [-exec xprog] gofiles... [arguments...]
> ```
>
> Run compiles and runs the main package comprising the named Go source
>   files. A Go source file is defined to be a file ending in a literal
>   ".go" suffix.

List all the `gofiles`,

```
go run main.go otherfile.go
```

Or, on Linux and other Unix-like systems, `*.go` is the wildcard for all `.go` files in the directory,

```
go run *.go
```

Comment: `go build` and/or `go install` are usually preferred once you have multiple *.go files, *_test.go files, build constraints, etc.